# How should I structure the Eloquent ORM models for multiple intermediate tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I can't find anywhere the information on how you have several intermediate tables with your Eloquent ORM models. The problem I'm facing is that I have a table for my users, permissions and roles. These are the 4 tables:

**Permissions:**

```
id
name
```

**Permission_roles:**

```
id
name
```

**Permission_role_mappings:**

```
id
permission_id
permission_role_id
```

**Permission_role_user_mappings:**

```
id
permission_role_id
user_id
```

(Well, I also have a `users` table but the layout of it doesn't matter since the foreign key is in `permission_role_user_mapping`.)

So the problem is that I want to be able to get the data from the `permissions` table when calling from the User model. I have some trouble grasping the workflow with Eloquent ORM altogether so if I'm missing something basic which is crucial then please point it out.

According to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#many-to-many) it seems that I don't need to create models for the intermediate tables. So how would I specify the relationship from the User class? Could I do something similar to this?

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function permission_role()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Permission_Role', 'permission_role_user_mappings');
    }

    public function permission()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Permission_Role', 'permission_role_user_mappings')->has_many_and_belongs_to('Permission','permission_role_mappings');
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, this is the error:

```
User::find(1)->first()->permission()->first();
...
Method [permission] is not defined on the Query class.
```

I also want to be able to get data by starting from Permission_Role and Permission. I'd prefer that the answer would help me specifying all the models required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent relationships are accessed as an object property instead of a function.

```
User::find(1)->first()->permission;
```

You can wrap that above statement in the `dd` function to get a look at it.

This [guide on Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.io/topic/14/how-eloquent-relationship-methods-work) should be helpful

Edit for question in comments about selecting all permissions in the role:

```php
$roles = array();
$permission_roles = User::find(1)->permission_roles()->get();
foreach ($permission_roles as $pr) {
  if (! in_array($pr->permissions)) {
    $roles[] = $pr->permissions;
  }
}
```

This will get you what you want. However, this will end up doing a lot of queries. It's best to make use of `Eager Loading` here.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, do note that Laravel has a convention for table names of many to many relationships. See this link for how to name them: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: I've adjusted my models so that they are now properly connected, but I can only select all the permissions from one role (`$roles = User::find(1)->permission_roles()->first()->permissions;`) how do I select all the permissions of all connected roles?